# NopCommerce PayPalStandart PDTHandler expects GET while PayPal uses POST

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.3

I want to configure PayPal standard plugin to receive payments.
Plugin Version: 1.60, NopCommerseVersion: 4.30

I've followed steps described here [here](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/getting-started/configure-payments/payment-methods/paypal-standard.html)
I've created business PayPal account
I configured under
Account settings > Website payments > Website preferences (https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website)
Auto return for website payments: Set to "On" and entered my site URL:
http://.../Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler
also I set
Payment data transfer: to "On"

After redirecting to PayPal, I've logged in and made a payment. And by pressing "Return to merchant", I was expected PayPal would redirect to http://.../Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler.
But instead of GET, PayPal used post

Request URL: http://.../Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler
Request Method: POST
and posts Form parameters:
payer_email: sb-bncsr3383810@personal.example.com
payer_id: JBH2JMEFAZEN2
payer_status: VERIFIED
first_name: John
last_name: Doe
...

NopCommerce website reutrns
Status Code: 400 Bad Request

I looked at PDTHandler code in nopCommerce, it expects GET and reads parameters from QueryString, but PayPal uses POST.
Is it possible to configure PayPal for it to use GET, or am I missing some configuration in NopCommerce part?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, that in PayPal Standard settings I specified Sandbox: true, Business email: actual business email. And payed from sandbox accounts.

After I specified Business email: sandbox business email. PayPal started to redirect properly, my site received GET request from PayPal.

Comment: But payment status is Pending? Is this the expected behavior of PayPal sandbox?